# Which tool to use for deploying Docker containers when scalability and availability are not a concern?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment

I'm looking to deploy some code in Docker containers into production and need to be able to deploy and schedule containers as required.

I had a look at Kubernetes and it would generally suit my use case. At the same time the applications I'll be deploying don't require high availability and scalability is also not a concern and it will be deployed on a local server.

So with that in mind I feel like K8s might be a bit of an overkill and I should just use something simple and easy and I can migrate to K8s in the future if I need to scale the app (which is not likely at the moment).

What would be alternative tools to use in this case?

Comment: what is the steady-state rate of change of this system?

Comment: @BruceBecker, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Apart from the initial setup, how often will changes be delivered to this environment?

Comment: @BruceBecker, the code will run individual batch jobs getting setup parameters when initialising a Docker container and then run to completion with no alterations. Basically just a bunch of lengthy parameterised calculations.

Comment: So why not just `docker run` or `docker compose` them (+ cron or something)? From what you're saying (lengthy parameterized calculations on a local server) that would be more than enough, and you can mount the input/output files directly from your file-system.